# Is VMware Fusion Player a suitable substitute for Bootcamp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, virtualization, vmware, fax

The goal is to be setup a Catlina (iMac 27-inch 2015, 32GB core i7) Machine with USB Fax Modem capability.  I have an Apple USB Fax Modem, however I am open to the idea of purchasing the US Robotics as prescribed in these instructions:

https://machow2.com/fax-from-mac-modem/

The instructions call for installing El Capitan with Boot camp.   I have installed an El Capitan VM on VMware Fusion player.

Is there some **necessary** advantage with Boot Camp over VMware Fusion player for said exercise?

The instructions indicates that the Apple Modem works only with OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and below.

Comment: Bootcamp runs windows not macOS. That makes no sense for running Catalina or el cap. [Linux and windows fax hardware cost $20](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=usb+fax+modem+linux) so it’s not clear if you need macOS or just a working setup based on unknown hardware.

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

You can install El Capitan on your model Mac to dual boot with your existing Catalina. Installing El Capitan would **not** involve the use the Boot Camp Installer. As you have already stated, you can also install El Capitan in a VMware Fusion player virtual machine. Note the following.

- Using VM would allow you to use El Capitan and Catalina at the same time. With a dual boot, you would have to restart to switch between the two operating systems.
- El Capitan in a VM may not be fast enough to be used for Faxing. Or, you may have to allocate enough resources (such as memory or processors) to the VM so that Catalina be unacceptable slow. With a dual boot arrangement, El Capitan and Catalina would not share resources other than disk space.
- With a VM there could exist a hardware (or virtual hardware) incompatibility which would prevent Faxing.

The necessary advantage with dual boot over VMware Fusion player for said exercise would occur if a VM arrangement did not work. This could occur if there is insufficient performance or a hardware (or virtual hardware) incompatibility the would not exist with a dual boot arrangement.